# Create a string router, not http / cli / browser

Tags: node.js, websocket, routes

I have a web socket connection, and it sends me some params. I want to route that params string input on my node.js apps.

I've searching, and got no idea what can i use for this. I'm trying using "Director" [https://github.com/flatiron/director] but, i can't pass any params to the routing function. example :

```
router.dispatch('on', wsReq.path); // wsReq is string input

router.on('/device/register', function () { // routing, but cant get any params from input
    console.log('asup');
});
```

I'm trying to googling for that problem, and got no solution because so many routing just for http on node.js

Anyone can suggest a library / solution? It will be a great help!

Thanks

**UPDATE - Solution**

Using an event emitter :

```
var MyEvents = require('events').EventEmitter;
var MyEventz = new MyEvents();

MyEventz.on('/device/register', function (all){

    console.log(all);

});

MyEventz.emit(wsReq.path, {aku:true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#) like this:

```
// UPDATE - missing 'new' keyword
//var MyEvents = require('events').EventEmitter();

var events = require('events');
var MyEvents = new events.EventEmitter()

MyEvents.emit(wsReq.path, all, the, args, you, need, here);

// assuming wsReq.path === '/device/register'
MyEvents.on('/device/register', function (all, the, args, you, need, here){

    console.log(all, the, args, you, need, here);

});
```

Comment: It's undefined, it give me `MyEvents.on('/device/register', function (all){
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` . do i have to install something with npm? but i see on your reference link its already on node.js

Comment: @MochammadZachri sorry i missed `new` keyword, i've updated the code